# Reverse DNS from a cloned linode

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, reverse-dns, dns-hosting, linode

I have cloned a linode1 that is linked to mydomain.com and the reverse DNS is li19034-215.members.linode.com;

the reverse DNS of the cloned linode is also li19034-215.members.linode.com; I wouls like to delete the reverse DNS and assign it to the same iP : 172.105.236.228 or delete it, but when I try it I have the error: `Domain is not valid.`

Comment: Many services check that the forward DNS resolves to the IP you are trying to set the reverse entry for.  Is this the case or not?  If yes, then a support ticket to Linode would be the suggested action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're trying to change the rDNS, but as I recall, it is the domain block owner who has this ability. Given that Linode is a bit larger than a couple of racks, they usually [allow you to modify this yourself](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/configure-your-linode-for-reverse-dns/).

My guess is that you don't have an `A record` that is pointing to your IP address. That is a prerequisite to setting up a `PTR record` pointing at the domain.

Hope that helps, good luck!